# How do i set up 'make install' to check the md5 of the installed libs/bins and only installed if changed?

Tags: gnu-make, autoconf, automake

I've inherited a fairly large project that is built using autoconfigure/automake (the configure.ac/Makefile.am files have their own issues, but that's a separate question).

My problem is that a top level build + build install generates several static and dynamic libs as well as binaries. So far so good. The problem is that 'make install' will indiscriminately copy over every single one of those libs/bins. (This takes a while)

I'd like it to only copy over libs/bins that have changed - potentially by comparing the md5sum of the target and source files.

How can i hook this up in my configure.ac/Makefile.am?

Comment: OK, so your comapre & copy `make install` scheme reads two files, compares, and possibly writes one file.  The usual `make install` reads one file, writes one file.  How long is this "while" that it takes?  Seconds? Minutes?  What runtime are you hoping to achieve with your scheme?

Comment: You're right - the copy time was on the order of minutes. I implemented the '-C' option suggested below, and it did not result in any noticeable speedup at all.

Comment: OK, then at least you have a baseline for trying other things.  There's a few articles on SO that ask about building on a RAM disk.  That could be tried.  But it could be possible that your build might be hitting some other hardware limit (e.g. CPU), so building on a RAM disk might not have a great effect either.  You'll have to find out what's really going on (both with the build itself and with the build hardware) to make your build faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual program to copy the files is `install` (usually `/usr/bin/install`); this is defined in the `INSTALL` Make-variable.

Your `install` implementation might support the `-C` flag:

```
   -C, --compare
          compare each pair of source and destination files, 
          and in some cases, do not modify the destination at all
```

you might have to 
So you could try to provide a script that does what you want (compare the source file with the destination file, and only copy if needed), by overriding this variable.
You could also just injec tthe `-C` flag, to see if it gives you any speedup (I tend to agree with ldav1s' comment that it might not):

```
make install INSTALL="/usr/bin/install -C"
```

note, that `install` accepts quite a number of arguments, and if you are going to re-implement a compatible script, you might have to implement some sub-set thereof.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I implemented this, and it didn't result in any appreciable speedup. But still good to know!